# drawing an ellipse in wpf from within a secondary thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading, canvas, ellipse

I am writing a wpf application in which balls are bouncing independently on a canvas, each ball in a different thread. Each time the user clicks on the canvas a new thread is added to the threadpool and an ellipse representing the ball is created. In order to add the ellipse and draw it I use Dispatcher.Invoke. However, the command myCanvas.Children.Add(el); called from within the code surrounded by Invoke causes the application to crash the moment the Invoke block ends, by entering break mode. 
Obviously, this is not the way to achieve my goal, so how can I do it?

```
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            Ellipse el = new Ellipse();
            el.Fill = color1;
            el.Margin = new Thickness(10);
            el.Height = 40;
            el.Width = 40;
            balls.Add(ballsCounter, el);
            Canvas.SetTop(el, p.Y - 2 * el.Height / 3);
            Canvas.SetLeft(el, p.X - 2 * el.Width / 3);
            myCanvas.Children.Add(el);
            tbNumBalls.Text = ballsCounter.ToString();
        }));
```

Comment: "each ball in a different thread" sounds like a massive waste of resources. Each thread would sleep most of the time, waiting for the next move cycle. I'd suggest to use a single DispatcherTimer to cyclically update the positions of all balls.

Comment: Thanks, Clemens. It is more of an exercise in multithreading. I am just curious to know what went wrong

Comment: Well, in order to get any help here, you would at least have to tell us which exception occured, and at which line in your code. Use your debugger.

Comment: In the last line in the code above I get the Break Mode tab saying "The application is in break mode".

Comment: I coded up your issue and it works fine.  So something else is wrong.  Perhaps you are using the wrong dispatcher?  You need to provide exception.  The reason the application is in break mode is that an exception has been thrown.

Comment: I don't see any exception. Which dispatcher did you use?

Comment: I am trying to catch an exception, but it keeps showing the break mode tab

Answer (score 1):

You can't create the `Ellipse` on one (UI) thread and then add it to a `Canvas` that was created on another (UI) thread.

This is not possible because of fact that WPF uses a single threaded exeuction model with thread affinity. This basically means that a UI control *cannot* be accessed from any other thread than the one on which it was originally created. There are checks in the base classes that enforce this by throwing `InvalidOperationException`s whenever you try to do this.

So you should either create all controls on the same thread, or keep them forever separated on different threads.